# Can we read data directly from disk/ssd without involving main memory?

Tags: memory, program-entry-point, ram, disk

I asked my University professor but could not get a proper understanding as he pointed out we won't have anything to store to. And that transferring directly isn't secure. I am not sure about the reasoning that's why using the community.

Comment: This is highly system dependent.  Are you asking about a particular real-life system, or ways in which a hypothetical system might be designed?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a programming question